# Is Wisdom modifier added to the damage roll of Astral Self Monk's AoE attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk

I'm specifically referring to this ability:

> When you do so, each creature of your choice that you can see within 10 feet of you must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take force damage equal to two rolls of your Martial Arts die.

I'm assuming that the wording is very specific on this and you don't add any stat modifiers to the damage roll, but I wanted to be sure and ask, just in case. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### It does what it says in the tin.

You have assumed correctly; the feature reads:

> As a bonus action, you can spend 1 ki point to summon the arms of your astral self. When you do so, each creature of your choice that you can see within 10 feet of you must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take force damage equal to two rolls of your Martial Arts die.

There is nothing here that allows you to add your wisdom modifier to this particular damage, so it is not added. Reviewing the rest of the subclass features, none of those add to this damage either. There are a few things that you can use your wisdom modifier for with the Arms of the Astral Self feature, *but they are explicitly stated in the feature description*:

> - You can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength modifier when making Strength checks and Strength saving throws.
> - [...]
> - The unarmed strikes you make with the arms can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength or Dexterity modifier for the attack and damage rolls, and their damage type is force.

Finally, I can give an example of a different monk feature that does some damage that includes the wisdom modifier, as a way of showing how the feature would typically be worded if you were to include the modifier. The Way of Mercy Monk has a feature called Hand of Harm, that reads (emphasis mine):

> You use your ki to inflict wounds. When you hit a creature with an unarmed strike, you can spend 1 ki point to deal extra necrotic *damage equal to one roll of your Martial Arts die + your Wisdom modifier.*

So if the area of effect damage from Arms of the Astral Self included your wisdom modifier, it would have read (my additions in brackets):

> or take force damage equal to two rolls of your Martial Arts die [+ your Wisdom modifier].

I very much empathize with your question here. Despite being a relatively experienced player and DM, I still find myself frequently asking players "don't you get to add X modifier to that?", when the answer is quite often "no".

Comment: Ah, I see. I was almost certain you wouldn't add modifiers unless it said, but I wanted to make absolutely sure. I really appreciate the very in depth answer, so thank you very much!

Comment: @deathsign092 I added a little note at the end, I very much get where you're coming from. I ask my players/DM all the time "do you add a modifier to that?", because sometimes it just feels right, even if it isn't. But welcome to the stack! Take the [tour] when you have a moment, and for more details, check out the [help] and our [FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/faq-index-for-role-playing-games-stack-exchange).

Comment: The usual nice thorough answer with experience base added also.  +1